# Area of section of cone cut by the plane

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, 3d

please help me solve this :-

prove that area of section of cone 
$$ bcx^2 + cay^2 + abz^2 = 0 $$ by the plane
$$ lx+my+nz = p $$ is

$$\frac{\pi p^2  \sqrt{abc}}{(al^2 + bm^2 + cn^2)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Hint: It is the area of an ellipse (in the favorable cases). If you find the lenghts of the semi major A and semi minor B axes, the area is $\pi A B.$

Comment: Do you have any ideas at all for how to proceed?